# Accurate types for a lookup of values of a string enum in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, enums

Suppose I have this string enum:

```
enum Color {
    None = "Q",
    Red = "R",
    Green = "G",
    Blue = "B",
}
```

Now, in TypeScript, [string enums have no reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), so I can't write `Color["Q"]` to obtain a potential `Color` back. I tried declaring my own helper function:

```
type StringEnum = {[key: string]: string};
function lookup<E extends StringEnum>(stringEnum: E, s: string): keyof E | undefined {
    for (const enumValue of keysOf(stringEnum)) {
        if (stringEnum[enumValue] === s) {
            return enumValue;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

with `keysOf` being

```
function keysOf<K extends {}>(o: K): (keyof K)[];
function keysOf(o: any) { return Object.keys(o); }
```

… but actually, I don't know what the return type should be. This is meant to compile, but doesn't:

```
const color: Color = lookup(Color, "Q") || Color.None;
```

because the return type of the `lookup` function is now `"None" | "Red" | "Green" | "Blue" | undefined` instead of just `Color | undefined`.

Can this be solved well while preserving the type information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `lookup` function returns an Enum string *key*, but you also provide the Enum *value* `Color.None` as short-circuit in case `lookup` returns undefined. So the types don't match here.

In general, string Enum keys can be typed like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-compile-time):

```
type ColorKeys = keyof typeof Color // "None" | "Red" | "Green" | "Blue"
const blueKey: keyof typeof Color = "Blue"
```

If you write `const blueValue = Color.None`, variable `blueValue` holds the Enum string value `"Q"`, not the literal `"None"`. So we can fix the `const color` assignment in the following way:

```
const color = lookup(Color, "Q") || "None";
// or with explicit type
const color: keyof typeof Color = lookup(Color, "Q") || "None";
```

Enum types [cannot have an index signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2491#issuecomment-145690830), so I typed `StringEnum` as `{[key: string]: any}` here to make it compile.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBW1AcnEYKAXigCIBFMgGixwCVgATE8+mu7AcWWFFbJcOOKACEEYIqTKiOAXwwYALgE8ADkQDKS5AEsQAcwCi4aKTQBtANbAVALigBnHfoMBdBwEMQKuQG4MADMwEABjJV0CKCQ4KzA1AB4jKGAADyVQJkcobT1DE0gAPgAKZzzjUwcjaicHMtcASgcbFThAqGSAHygQpmBA-WZ0TihAlChi0IJnFNMANU8JIjaoFscAeUDSl3zTBobhkRFddu3ygogLUEgFpbcSYlJHA8wjt6heJTBkEFmbxckAXeUAUIlBOE+31+vX6gyYAQUQRC4UivzWmwSAGkUulMtk0HISnAHJimhMWitSRY3AFgmEIlF0VtiVBvCoXh9gF8flB1gAjABWwHCADo1sU4A0-CDFBgpiAZlMkMhmrYVqoNCt4MrWDE4mpitqUDVKGQDp1umR8IQyAFlOoiEbkJjbNlSBT2hrgFrEOMAPR+qBe2C+52ugTW4BkKCWxhMaOWnh8EAJ8jiSRkRTymZ8pa3SSsJ0i9NEAMCWRQOXTJRQXOSF32VZqz0On066Ql6OyjBAA)

#### Update: get typed enum value from `lookup`

If you want to pass in an unnarrowed string value to `lookup` and give it back as narrowed enum value type if existent (otherwise `undefined`), you can do it  in a similar way to your first example:

```
function lookup<E extends StringEnum>(
  stringEnum: E,
  s: string
): E[keyof E] | undefined {
  for (const enumKey of keysOf(stringEnum)) {
    if (stringEnum[enumKey] === s) {
      // here we have to help the compiler
      return stringEnum[enumKey] as E[keyof E];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

// let's test it
const look = lookup(Color, "Q") // const look: Color | undefined

// for further understanding
type AllColorKeys = keyof typeof Color // = "None" | "Red" | "Green" | "Blue"
type AllColorValues = (typeof Color)[keyof typeof Color] // = Color
type IsColorSuperType = Color.Blue extends Color ? true: false // = true
```

In case of `Color` enum, the returned [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) will give you back value `Q` with type `Color | undefined`, as the union of all possible `Color` enum values `Color.None`, `Color.Red` and so on will be of supertype `Color`. The defined enum construct itself has the type `typeof Color`, comparable to the [static and instance side of a class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwFBSgOTiYKAXigCIBFUgGiygCVgATYsu62gcWWFBdI-bYAQgjCESpIaQwBfDBgAuATwAOhAMoLkASxABzAKLhoJNFADaAa2BKAXFADOW3XoC69gIYglUGQG55ADMwEABjBW18KCQ4SzAVAB4DKGAADwVQRgcoTR19I0gAPgAKWic8w2N7AxpsB3tylwwASmqrGzhAqANXKAAfKBDGYEDdJnRaQJQoYtD8JxTjAGkbKE6oayUHAHlA4sb842bmiexsbS7950PIc1BIFaVeohfHE8wzs+4FMGQQR2ulVu9wgj16HmyBnaSnWPQCnzk2ERUG+v3+QxGY0YATkGGCYQiUU2O0CCSWKXSmWyaBkJTg9iWrRmm3WjPMrgC+PCkX+xN2xXpUC8SnetFRfyg2wARgArYDhAB0xIFzRx8jmIAWMUsLG18WK8CQyCoZEoJwA9OaoBqtXBYvZDdMBhjRgRGEA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, this works—but it actually goes the opposite way of what I wanted. I want my lookup function to return the enum value, and I don't know how to type it to get the precise type depending on the enum that I'm passing. I don't realize if the link you provided indicates that this actually isn't possible.

Comment: No sure, if I have understood that correctly: your `lookup`, as it is defined in your question, returns the enum keys (like for`const color`, which saves enum key "None"). You could then write `const result = Color[color]`, result would contain your enum value "Q" with the type `Color`. You could also write `const str: string = "None"; const result = Color[str as keyof typeof Color]` to get the value from an unnarrowed string.

Comment: Actually, I want `lookup` to return `Color | undefined` depending on whether the passed argument is one of the string values used to represent a `Color`.

Comment: Great! `E[keyof E]` is really the piece I was missing. Thanks!